# Connect to Ubuntu machine protected with .pem file using VNC, in order to execute GUI applications

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vnc, aws

The title pretty much says it all.

For now, I can connect to the specified Ubuntu machine using `ssh -i pem_file_name username@ip_address`, assuming that I am on the directory where the .pem file resides.

I need to connect to the same machine using the VNC (or any other protocol for that matter), enabling me thus to execute applications that use a graphical user interface. I need to do this by using the same .pem file.

Another mention would be that this is an AWS machine, so it has a firewall that make some ports unusable.

What steps can I take in order to make this possible ?

Comment: Does your VNC client have an option to configure + connect via an SSH tunnel?

Comment: I am using Remmina client for this task. It has the option to enable SSH tunnel. I will provide more information about how I am using the client.